# Ink bar under centered tabs not being aligned properly when opening sidenav using Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to add some tabs on top of my page, and I want to center them. I am however getting the ink bar under the tabs misaligned when I open the sidenav. Clicking on either tab will reset the ink bar, and reposition it correctly though. How can I make the ink bar be aligned properly?

I am using `ViewEncapsulation.None` on my component, and I have overriden the css for `mat-tab-list` like this:

```
.mat-tab-list{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Maybe there is another (proper) way to center the tabs so that I can avoid this behaviour?

I have made a stackblitz to reproduce the problem,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thrvh6 (problem occurs on desktop sized windows, not on mobile sized windows)

Comment: I published another workaround for align `mat-ink-bar` https://stackoverflow.com/a/64975309/9026103

Answer (score 1):

It seems that setting the sidenav's `mode` property to `push` fixes the problem. However, it changes how the components are displayed, as the content on the right is partially greyed-out when the sidenav is open; whether this is an acceptable behaviour is up to you.

Comment: Certainly the ink bar is aligned properly if the mode is set to push, however, I want to interact with the content even though the sidenav is open. Why the content is "pushed" differently is kind of strange. +1 for the attempt though.

Comment: If I don't center the tabs, the `side`-mode works as expected. Maybe there is a bug inside Angular Material?

Comment: It might as well be a library bug. I have not found any reference to similar problems, so it might be worth opening a feature / bugfix request to address this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will do that.

Comment: Actually, this is a similar issue: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10340
There seems to be an open pull request to fix it

Comment: Thanks for the research. I will add a comment refering this question.

Answer (score 0):

I also have ran into this issue. The mat-ink-bar does not recalculate when there is a material side nav with the mode set to "side". Here is my work around with css (I am hiding the mat-ink-bar and using &:after styling):

```
.mat-tab-label-active {
    .mat-tab-label-content {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: black;

      &:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background: $blue-3;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
      }
   }
}

mat-ink-bar {
  display: none !important;
}
```