# mat-ink-bar location not update when container resizes

Tags: angular, angular-material

I using angular-material `mat-tab-nav-bar`

I have side menu on the right side of the screen, click on it change the width of the side menu, and the center screen width change according to the menu width.

the problem is that the mat-ink-bar right/left position not changed.

[image: mat-tab-nav-bar with open menu]

[image: mat-tab-nav-bar with close menu]

Any idea?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz of you code

Comment: If @Hargun's comment solved your issue, would you please mark is as accepted.

Comment: I posted a similar question a while back. Please have a look [Ink bar under centered tabs not being aligned properly when opening sidenav using Angular Material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485527/ink-bar-under-centered-tabs-not-being-aligned-properly-when-opening-sidenav-usin)

Answer (score 9):

You can force the ink bar to re-align by calling realignInkBar() on mat-tab-group,check out this example  on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/realighinkbar-example)

To read further on the bug check out this [thread](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14462)

**Example: (TabsComponent)**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  templateUrl: './tabs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabs.component.css']
})
export class TabsComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('tabs', {static: false}) tabs;
  selectedIndex: number;

  isHidden: boolean = true;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toggleExpandCard() {
    this.tabs.realignInkBar(); // Remove this line to 'break' the example
    this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
  }

}
```

**Example: (tabs.component.html)**

```
<div class="header">
  <button type="button"(click)="toggleExpandCard()">
    Click here to {{isHidden ? 'show' : 'hide'}} tabs!
  </button>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tabs-wrapper" [hidden]="isHidden">
  <mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex" #tabs>
    <mat-tab label="Earth">
      <p>...is round</p>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Wind">
      <p>...can be painful</p>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Fire">
      <p>...requires attention</p>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you just copy+paste your `tabs.component.ts` code? Your fiddle link may eventually rot.

Comment: I also had the problem that the mat-ink-bar was at a random place in combination with `mat-align-tabs="center"`. You can also call the function with `realignInkBar()` when the user clicks on the tab itself: `<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="center" #tabs (selectedTabChange)="doRealignInkBar()">`. Thank you Hargun you saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK mat-tab-nav-bar unlike mat-tab-group does not have realignInkBar() instead you need to use _alignInkBarToSelectedTab() on mat-tab-nav-bar like below code:

```
  <nav #tabs mat-tab-nav-bar mat-stretch-tabs>
    <a  mat-tab-link
       *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
       [routerLink]="link.link"
       routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
       [active]="rla.isActive"
       style="text-decoration: none">
      <span {{ link.label }}</span>
    </a>
    <a mat-tab-link >Disabled Link</a>
  </nav>
```

At your Component first you need to define tabs as @ViewChild and then call the method:

```
 @ViewChild('tabs', {static: false}) tabs;
  realignInkBar() {
    // this.tabs.realignInkBar();
    this.tabs._alignInkBarToSelectedTab();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best solution ever, but as a workaround, it works.

In my case content loads, and causes a vertical scrollbar, it resizes the page a bit (but `window.onresize` doesn't catch this resize event, so can't catch it yet), and sets the wrong alignment to `mat-ink`. My workaround - listen for routing event, wait for content loading by setTimeout with 1sec delay and realign `mat-ink`.

```
@ViewChild('matTabsRef', { static: false }) matTabsRef: MatTabNav;

fixResizeInkBar() {
  setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.matTabsRef) {
        this.matTabsRef._alignInkBarToSelectedTab();
      }
    }, 1000);
}

private listenRoutes(): void {
    this.subs.add(
      this.router.events
        .pipe(
          filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
          startWith(true)
        )
        .subscribe((event) => {
          this.fixResizeInkBar();
        })
  );
}
```