# Angular Mat Ink Bar / Bar Below Tab is Occasionally Not Centered

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, tabs

Note: I've already reviewed the question and answers at [Ink bar under centered tabs not being aligned properly when opening sidenav using Angular Material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485527/ink-bar-under-centered-tabs-not-being-aligned-properly-when-opening-sidenav-usin)
but this did not help me arrive at a solution.

**It seems that at random times I am seeing the bar below an Angular Material Tab (called the mat ink bar) not being centered:**

[image]

**But then if I refresh the page it's fine:**

[image]

I have the following in my .scss file related to the mat tabs:

```
/* Styles for the **active** tab label */
.mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    color: black !important;
} 

/* Styles for the ink bar */
.mat-ink-bar {
    // transition: none !important;
    transition-duration: 250ms !important;;
   
}
.mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar{
    background-color: #0076C0;
    background: #0076C0;
} 
.remove-border-bottom .mat-tab-header {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

And the following html for the tab group / tab:

```
    <mat-tab-group #tabs class="remove-border-bottom" dynamicHeight [selectedIndex]="this.indexOfFirstSessionInNewlyOpened" animationDuration="0ms" (selectedTabChange)="onSessionTabChanged($event)" disableRipple="true">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let session of openedSessionsData">
            <mat-tab style="overflow-y: hidden !important;" ​>
               ...
            </mat-tab>
        </ng-container>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Hard to see anything wrong with what you have provided. Have you been able to reproduce this in stackblitz or elsewhere?